# X,Y independent and normally distributed. What is the expected length and angle of the vector (X,Y)?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X, Y$ be independent, normally distributed random variables with equal variances and means $\mu_X, \mu_Y$. What is the expected length of the vector $(X,Y)$ and what is the expected angle with respect to the $x$-axis?

If the means are $0$, then the length is Rayleigh distributed and the angle is uniformly distributed. But what if the means are not $0$? Is there a way to calculate the integrals to get their mean and variance (or other properties)?

Comment: How many dimensions?

Comment: For simplicity, I am looking at X, Y one-dimensional

Comment: Okay, I found that the length is Rice-distributed, but I couldn't find anything on the angle yet

Comment: @ab2 well the angle is $\tan^{-1}(Y/X)$ so you should be good to go if you know the distribution of $Y/X$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution

Comment: may have to do some adjustment for the quadrant of $(X,Y)$ though

Comment: You can easily make a coordinate transformation to polar coordinates and then marginalise r, no need for using arctan or adjusting quadrants. The issue is that the resulting integrals don't seem easy to solve

Comment: Related (non-zero mean, isotropic case): https://farid.berkeley.edu/downloads/publications/arxiv20a.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reference. They apply the same coordinate transformation as I've tried and simplify it further. I'll look at their reference to see if there's more known about the distribution

Comment: By symmetry, the expected angle is the angle of the expected values. No luck with the variance though, and the 1972 reference states that "the distribution theory necessary for statisti­cal inference [...] is formidable"